# Find Minimum area of given hexagon. Geometry Question.

Tags: geometry, area

It has been a year Since I am searching for an answer to this question.
This question was probably asked in International Mathematics Olympiad but I am not a 100% sure.

Q : ABCDEF Is a concave hexagon. Let P be a random point on inside hexagon. Suppose $[APB] = 4$ , $[CPD] = 6$ and $[EPF] = 9$. (Here $[ABC]$ denotes the area of triangle $ABC$). What is the minimum possible area of **hexagon** $ABCDEF$ ?

[image: hexagon]

Comment: In your picture, ABCDEF is a convex hexagon because all angles are less than 180 degrees, but ABCDEFP is not a convex heptagon because the angle at P is greater than 180 degrees.  Did you mean ABCDEF is convex?

Comment: Are the lines APD, BPE, CPF, supposed to be straight?

Comment: Nope #extra words to increase comment length#

Answer (score 1):

At least one among triangles $APB$, $CPD$ or $EPF$ must lie entirely inside the hexagon, so its area is at least $4$. On the other hand, the difference between the hexagon area and $4$ can be made as small as one wishes, as shown for example in the picture below.
[image]

In this case we have a degenerate hexagon whose area is $4+\epsilon$, and $\epsilon$ can be taken arbitrarily small. So the infimum of the area is 4.

EDIT

As Peter Shor's comment points out, my assumption that one among triangles $APB$, $CPD$ or $EPF$ must lie entirely inside the hexagon was wrong: his construction shows that the area of the hexagon can be vanishingly small.

In the picture below I followed his idea, but with a non-degenerate hexagon. Start the construction with an equilateral triangle $A'E'C'$ of side $2\sqrt3\epsilon$, so that its center $P$ is at a distance $\epsilon$ from its sides. 
Draw then points $A$, $C$ and $E$ on the sides of $A'E'C'$ such that
$AA'=CC'=EE'=\epsilon^2$. Finally, draw $B$, $D$ and $F$ on the extensions of the sides of $A'E'C'$ such that $AB=8/\epsilon$, $CD=12/\epsilon$ and $EF=18/\epsilon$. 
The conditions on the areas of $PAB$, $PCD$ and $PEF$ are satisfied, while
the area of hexagon $ABCDEF$ turns out to be 
$$
area={19\over3}\sqrt3\epsilon+3\sqrt3\epsilon^2
-{9\over2}\epsilon^3+{3\over4}\sqrt3\epsilon^4.
$$

[image]

This tends to zero as $\epsilon\to0$, so the infimum of hexagon area is zero.

Comment: I don't get how is ABCDEF is a hexagon acc to your diagram. Also all these points are meant to be distinct.

Comment: I don't believe it's true that one of APB, CPD, EPF, lies inside the hexagon. I have drawn a counterexample, but it's hard to post in this comment. You need to add a proof of this fact to the answer, if it's true.

Comment: @PeterShor I'd be very interested in seeing a counterexample: I confess I haven't thought much about that, so it may well be wrong.

Comment: @AV198 It is a degenerate hexagon, but that is of no concern here: just imagine to move very slightly $A$ and $B$ towards the center, to get a non degenerate hexagon as near as you want to the one I showed.

Comment: Here's a construction which I think works. Take a small equilateral triangle ACE, with P at the center. Put point F on the extension of edge EA in the direction of A. Put point B on the extension of edge AC in the direction of C. Put point D on the extension of edge CE in the direction of E. Placing points B, D, F properly and perturbing them by a tiny amount will give a hexagon with area roughly the area of the original equilateral triangle, and with arbitrary areas for the three triangles PAB, PCD, PEF.

Comment: @PeterShor Great! That shows the lowest area is zero!

Comment: @Aretino: beautiful figure! Thanks.

Comment: @PeterShor I slightly altered your construction, to allow for a non-degenerate hexagon and avoid tiresome criticisms.